# Optimizing subsetting with data.table in a loop

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I have a basic question on how to optimize the following code. This is a very very abbreviated version of my code. Basically, I have a large data.table (> 50M rows) and I would like to subset the data very often (say 10000 times) and run some function on the subset (obviously more complicated than the one shown in the example below, i.e. I need all columns of the subset and the function returns a new data.table). I just picked the mean to make the example simple.

```
dt <- data.table(a=sample(letters, 1000000,replace=T),b=sample(1:100000))

mm <- list()

foo <- function(x) mean(x$b)

for(i in 1:1000)
{
  mm[[i]] <-  foo(dt[a %in% sample(letters,5)])
}
```

It is obvious that this is not the fastest way to program even this minimal example (setting keys etc.).

I am interested, however, how to optimize the for loop. I had in mind to create indices for the subsets and then use data.table `dt[,foo(.SD),by=subset_ID]` , but I am not sure on how to this, since I am sampling with replacement (multiple group IDs). Any ideas based on data.table would be much appreciated (e.g. how to remove the loop?).

Comment: If your foo actually only needs one column, it's a little faster (~15-20%) to select that column from `dt` before passing it to foo.

Comment: Btw, if you want to edit the question to make an example that illustrates better, I could add a "bounty" ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty ), maybe attracting more/better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I had in mind to create indices for the subsets and then use data.table `dt[,foo(.SD),by=subset_ID]`, but I am not sure on how to this, since I am sampling with replacement (multiple group IDs).

With a join, you can have overlapping groups:

```
# convert to numeric
dt[, b := as.numeric(b)]

# make samples
set.seed(1)
mDT = setDT(melt(replicate(1000, sample(letters,5))))
setnames(mDT, c("seqi", "g", "a"))

# compute function on each sample
dt[mDT, on=.(a), allow.cartesian=TRUE, .(g, b)][, .(res = mean(b)), by=g]
```

which gives

```
         g      res
   1:    1 50017.85
   2:    2 49980.03
   3:    3 50093.80
   4:    4 50087.67
   5:    5 49990.83
  ---              
 996:  996 50013.11
 997:  997 50095.43
 998:  998 49913.61
 999:  999 50058.44
1000: 1000 49909.36
```

To confirm it's doing the right thing, you can check eg,

```
dt[a %in% mDT[g == 1, a], mean(b)]
# [1] 50017.85
```

One downside of this approach is that it involves creating a very large table (containing the data for all the samples), which may put you in trouble, RAM-wise.

This approach is taking advantage of your function being `mean`, since passing it explicitly allows for certain optimizations; see `?GForce`, which is also why I converted `b` to numeric.

I agree with Rob Jensen's suggestion to pass columns to the function instead of passing a table (with the function making assumptions about what columns appear in the table), both for efficiency and clarity.

In the specific case of taking the mean, you could speed this up further by adding up for each letter first, I think:

```
dtagg = dt[, .(.N, sumb = sum(b)), by=a]

dtagg[mDT, on=.(a), .(g, sumb, N)][, lapply(.SD, sum), by=g][, .(g, res = sumb/N)]

         g      res
   1:    1 50017.85
   2:    2 49980.03
   3:    3 50093.80
   4:    4 50087.67
   5:    5 49990.83
  ---              
 996:  996 50013.11
 997:  997 50095.43
 998:  998 49913.61
 999:  999 50058.44
1000: 1000 49909.36
```

`allow.cartesian` is not needed in this case, since each row of `mDT` finds only a single row in `dtagg`. On my computer, the speedup with the example data is pretty big, but most of the benefit comes from taking advantage of the form of the example function, I guess:

- 13.7 sec OP's approach
- 11.4 sec simple join
- 0.02 sec aggregate-first

Comment: Thank you, Frank. I understand your solution. However, I am worried about creating a 1000 x 50M rows data set, because of RAM limitations (as you mentioned as well). I will try this out tomorrow. Any other suggestion without "allow.cartesian", would be nice. Note, the function foo is NOT the mean (this was just an example).

Comment: @PukiLuki Yeah, the only thing I can think of is to be to be familiar with the aggregate-first strategy and see if it can be applied to your actual function. If not, I think a loop is a good approach. If you need a speedup, you could also look at parallelization packages (since each run is independent of the others).